# 1-channel GPIO from industrial PC over RS232 port

Tags: gpio, rs232, rs485, rs422

I am ordering a computer based on 4x4-R1000V motherboard (Ryzen Embedded, https://www.asrockind.com/overview.asp?Model=4X4-R1000V) for an industrial application.

I need a 1-channel GPIO (0 for zero, >1V for one). The board has on-board `1 x COM(RS-232/422/485)`.

My question is: is it possible to drive one (any) pin on the connector as a GPIO from Linux? Is it perhaps chipset-dependent?

I spotted [Possible to use a 9 Pin Serial port as “GPIO” using ioctl()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789099/possible-to-use-a-9-pin-serial-port-as-gpio-using-ioctl) suggesting it is shoudl work, but I'd rather have a confirmation from hardware folks here.

Comment: Typically you can use one of the modem control signals on the serial port.  Be aware these are not logic voltages.  But questions about PC hardware are off topic here, this site is for design questions concerning documented systems, not for guessing at the specifications of products.

Comment: For long-term reliability and compatibility I would strongly suggest getting a USB or serial based IO board. Or something like a simple Arduino listening over USB serial for commands to toggle and input or output.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Though if this feature (pin control) is standard and documented for modem control through RS-232, not implementation-defined, that's the best; that's what the answers seem to suggest. Otherwise, point taken :)

Comment: @MadHatter Arduino over USB is my first choice for development, though it would complicate later stages ­– the whole machine will have to be CE-certified, assembling from stock CE-certified elements (such as the embedded computer) w/o extras is a plus (that is, as far as I understand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arbitrarily control at least the DTR and RTS lines of a RS-232 interface.

Example: https://github.com/xanthium-enterprises/RTS-DTR-Pin-Control-Linux/blob/master/serial_rts_dtr.c

Comment: I appreciate the code link, will make the start easier :)

Answer (score 1):

This used to be very simple to do with the parallel ports back in the day.

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/accessing-parallel-ports-on-linux/

The link you supplied concernig pin 9 of the serial port looks legit ! I am pretty confident it could work. But this is an input only... Also from the link you supplied you can see that outputting the "reference" voltages (for him to use a switch as an input) is kindof a hack (he is rectifying the serial output), but if you don't need to, that should be allright.

That is where I think you will need an adaptation of your game plan because the input signal should be, when negative, within -3 to -13V with respect to ground. And, when positive, it should be within +3 to +13V with respect to the ground.

There is a deadband in the RS232 specification that should discard everything within -3 to +3V with respect to the ground.

[image]

Comment: "this is an input only" *incorrect* your very own graphic shows signals going in both directions - DTR vs DSR, RTS vs CTS.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I might use diode to discard (for example) <0V, so I will have 0V for logical zero and >3V for logical one; the target device is not picky about voltage, it only needs ~zero for `0` and something in range 1…24V for `1`.

Comment: Yes a diode **and** a pull down resistor wired to signal ground should do the trick. Thus your "zero" is achieved by the resistor when the diode blocks the -12V and your "one" is achieved by the rs232 output when the diode lets the +12V through